# JSP calling a function from another jsp file

Tags: jsp

Hi
i have a JSP file , while trying to add code i got the 64k limit error.
so i decided to add the code to another jsp file and include it inside the first one.

### so i have

first.jsp

```
.....
<jsp:include page="second.jsp"/>
....
<%= foo(); %>
```

---

second.jsp
....

```
<%!
public String foo()
{
 return "test";
}
>%
```

---

i try using this and i get this error message:
"The method foo is undefined for the type first_jsp"

any idea what is the problem and how i can solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the wrong way to do it.

First, if you want some method, create a Java class, and import it using `<%@ page import="your.package.YourClass*" %>`

Second, don't use scriptlets in the JSP page at all. Use JSTL. Possibly JSTL functions. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: ok , so you are saying i should only use this <%= %> and avoid using java inside with those <% %>

Comment: you should not use these scriptlets at all

Comment: so if i understand correct i should put inside a jsp file only html and <%= x %> and do all my logic in a java class ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files see here

Answer (score 0):

Stop using scriptlets.  Use JSTL tags to access your data and write your Java code in servlets/regular java classes.