# how to call one jsp function from script of onother jsp page

Tags: jsp

I want to write a function say `count();` in one jsp page, and call it from script of another jsp page.

Can somebody suggest me how should I proceed? The `count()` function of the first jsp page is not defined in the script.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013063/jsp-calling-a-function-from-another-jsp-file

Answer (score 0):

you can use  tag.

```
<jsp:forward page={"relativeURL" | "<%= expression %>"} />
or
<jsp:forward page={"relativeURL" | "<%= expression %>"} >
<jsp:param name="parameterName"
          value="{parameterValue | <%= expression %>}" />+
</jsp:forward>
```

Examples

```
<jsp:forward page="/servlet/login" />
<jsp:forward page="/servlet/login">
<jsp:param name="username" value="jsmith" />
</jsp:forward>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. JSPs are used to view things. If your function is written in Java, then you should make another class that implements this function. In your JSPs, you import that class and this way it will work. You shouldn't write too much Java code in a JSP.